# How to run an ASM file in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, assembly, x86

App: VS Code version 1.65.2

OS:  Linux Mint 20.2 Cinnamon

I want to run the following code in Assembly:

```
    ;   The input is a decimal number,
    ;   Result is a hexadecimal number

section .text
    ;   to make the printf out work the main 'method' is needed
    global main
    
    ;   for printing numbers out
    extern printf

main:
    ;   Find factorial for the initial value of ecx,
    mov ecx, 5
    
    ;   Copy the initial value of ecx to eax, 
    ;   eax is our factorial result
    mov eax, ecx
    
loop:
    ;   If the counter is less or equal to 1, finish
    cmp ecx, 1
    jle end
    
    sub ecx, 1
    mul ecx
    jmp loop

end:
    ; Display the message and exit
    push eax
    push message
    call printf
    add esp, 8
    ret

section .data
    message: db "The result is = %08X", 10, 0
```

I have installed:

1. Cutting edge x86 and x86_64 assembly syntax highlighting.
2. Arm assembly syntax support for Visual Studio Code.

However, running the file in both extensions returns me the following:
**Code language not supported or defined.**

Comment: You know this is x86 assembly, right?  (looks like NASM syntax).  But you tagged this question [ARM].

Comment: I am a beginner in programming Assembly, I sought for information about any relevant extensions and I tried to run this code in order to start learning.

Comment: What kind of computer do you have?  Is it a normal PC desktop or laptop, with an x86 CPU?  Or are you doing this on a Raspberry Pi or something else with an ARM CPU?

Comment: System:    Kernel: 5.4.0-104-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 
                 Desktop: Cinnamon 5.0.7 wm: muffin dm: LightDM Distro: Linux Mint 20.2 
                 Uma  base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal

Comment: Laptop Acer Nitro V